# Selecting data from multiple dataframe columns and compiling into one list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm new to python and associated libraries and am hacking around on my own in a forest of syntax, datatypes etc. I'd greatly appreciate any advice on the following problem: I'm trying to select values from multiple columns ("Numbers" and "Numbers2" in the example below) in a dataframe based on a value in one column ("Letters") and then combine the values from the different columns into one list so I can do statistical analysis on the combined values. After a certain amount of trial and error, I've got the following which seems to work...but feels a bit clunky. Is there a better way?!

Many thanks!

```
Letters = ["A","B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"]
Numbers =[1,1,1,2,1,2,3]
Numbers2 =[10,10,10,20,10,20,30]

test_dict={"Letter":Letters, "Number":Numbers, "Number2":Numbers2}
test=pd.DataFrame(test_dict)

numbers_by_letters =[]

for unique_letter in test["Letter"].unique(): 
    numbers_by_letter =[]
    for col in range (1, 3) :
        number_by_letter=test[test["Letter"] == unique_letter].iloc[:,col]
        numbers_by_letter.extend(number_by_letter)
    numbers_by_letters.append(numbers_by_letter) 

print (numbers_by_letters)
```

The output I get is shown below and is what I think I want!

[`[1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 2, 10, 20], [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]]`

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you want to transform input into output? It's hard to understand it from your code.

Comment: Not sure I know how to answer the question! The input values in the dataframe contain float values and the output list of lists shown at the bottom has the output in the form I need. ie for each unique entry in the Letters column I now have a simple list of values  associated with that entry compiled form the different columns. Is that the info you needed? If not explain slowly and I'll try and naswer...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
print(
    test.groupby("Letter")
    .apply(lambda x: sorted(x[["Number", "Number2"]].to_numpy().flatten()))
    .to_list()
)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 2, 10, 20], [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]]
```

Comment: Cool - thanks! You're taking me out of my depth....In my real situation the number of columns I'm sampling from is a variable defined earlier in the code, which is why I set it up with the "col in range" structure. Can you solution be modified so that the numbre of columns varies?

Comment: @MontagnaBlue You can do `.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.iloc[:, 0:2].to_numpy().flatten()))` Note the `.iloc[:, 0:2]` to specify the range of columns.

Comment: Thanks - that's great!